# Is it possible to set SO_ORIGINAL_DST value of a socket?

Tags: sockets, go, networking, iptables

I'm trying trying to redirect a tcp connection to a transparent proxy without iptables. iptables is definitely not an option. Is it possible set original destination on a socket? Here is the code I wrote in go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

const (
    SO_ORIGINAL_DST = 80
)

func main() {
    proto := ((syscall.IPPROTO_IP << 8) & 0xff00) | ((syscall.IPPROTO_IP >> 8) & 0xff)
    sock, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, proto)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error while creating socket: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    }

    mreq := syscall.IPv6Mreq{
        Multiaddr: [16]byte{2, 0, 1, 187, 104, 28, 28, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        Interface: 0,
    }

    err = syscall.SetsockoptIPv6Mreq(sock, syscall.SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, &mreq)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error while setting original destination: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    }

    sa := syscall.SockaddrInet4{
        Port: 8080,
        Addr: [4]byte{127, 0, 0, 1},
    }
    err = syscall.Connect(sock, &sa)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error while connecting to target: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer syscall.Close(sock)

}
```

I use IPv6Mreq because it is the only struct type with 16 bytes and also it is the only option when getting SO_ORIGINAL_DST ([source](https://gist.github.com/fangdingjun/11e5d63abe9284dc0255a574a76bbcb1)). The above code returns

```
Error while setting original destination: protocol not available
```

Is only iptables allowed to set original destination or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I'm using debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO_ORIGINAL_DST is only used to get the original destination IP address of a redirected socket. The redirection itself must be done with iptables.

Comment: And it is only supported for get, not set.

Comment: Isn't it possible to write my own iptables? What makes iptables special?

Comment: @paddlesteamer: It is unclear why you are not able to use iptables in the first place so it is unclear what you consider "special". iptables is open source so no need to write your own (but you can, only it is far from trivial). The "special" requirements are that it works only with a Linux kernel (with netfilter support compiled in, which is pretty standard) and that you have to be root to add iptables rules.

Comment: I'm not able to use iptables because I'm trying to bridge two ethernet interfaces where vlan and pppoe packets pass through and ebtables doesn't call iptables PREROUTING table of iptables even though br_netfilter module and filter-pppoe/vlan-tagged enabled. So I wanted to simulate iptables myself  to redirect specific packets to my transparent proxy but nevermind I'm doing it with socks5 proxy now. But I'm curious if I would be able to set SO_ORIGINAL_DST by writing a kernel module? As long as I understand, iptables is allowed to set SO_ORIGINAL_DST because it is working in kernel space.

Comment: @paddlesteamer: Maybe you can write a kernel module which does this but I doubt it will be trivial. But maybe you are just too focused on trying to solve your problem in a very specific way and ignore other options to solve the actual problem. I recommend that you ask a new question where you describe the real problem you want to solve, your attempt to solve it with a bridge and the problems you run into of not being able to create a transparent proxy. Maybe someone with more expertise in such setups will give you an idea of a better approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is only use to get original address. e.g.

```
f, err := conn.(*net.TCPConn).File()
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
defer f.Close()
addr, err := syscall.GetsockoptIPv6Mreq(int(f.Fd()), syscall.IPPROTO_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```